# mysql reference aggregate table column name without alias

Tags: mysql

I did

```
create table tmp select min(xxx_id) from xxx group by y having count(*)>1;
```

now I need to join this tmp table with another table, but how do I reference the only column in side the tmp table?

```
select * from table2 s, tmp t where s.xxx_id=t.xxx_id?
```

clearly won't work, what should be replacing t.xxx_id?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to enclose that column in quotes as:

```
select * from table2 s, tmp t where s.xxx_id = t.`min(xxx_id)`;
```

but it's always better to give alias to columns as it's not confusing:

```
create table tmp select min(xxx_id) AS min_xxx_id from xxx group by y having count(*)>1;
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
select * 
from table2 s join tmp t  
on s.xxx_id=t.xxx_id
```